# Android - Accessing image from drawable folder and storing it in a data structure

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which I need to access images. The idea is, there are hundreds of images in the drawable folder, I have retrieve them and store it a data structure say hash map. Accessing each one by their id (R.drawable.image) is tiresome. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Your current approach would give you Out of memory exception when you are inserting bitmaps to the hashmap, I would recommend using LRUcache instead to prevent it.

Comment: Oh I will try it out